# How to make design for websites in Photoshop, according to WCAG 2.0 color contrast guideline?

Tags: web, accessibility, photoshop, wcag

What points should I keep in mind while designing. How we can make good design while keeping in mind color related Accessibility guideline of [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/)?

Comment: Better asked here: http://Doctype.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [excellent list of links to further information and tools](http://www.stcsig.org/usability/topics/colorblind.html) to help simulate the various conditions (note the simulations show you how different colours contrast against each other rather than being what a colour blind person actually sees).

The rule of thumb is never use only colour to convey information (so a green button marked ok is better than a green circle). Bear in mind that adding colour enhances usability so try to use it correctly rather than eliminate it. Secondly use the simulators to check the contrast of your colour scheme with the common conditions.